# Need to debug VB 6 DLL in VC++ code

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-c++, mfc, vb6

I am having one ActiveX control developed in VB 6.0. I am having VC++ code which host activeX control on it. 
I need to debug ActiveX control code without conversion into .NET in VC++.
After screening whole activeX folder, There are no PDB's for ACTIVEX control.

Question:

- ActiveX control code of VB 6.0 will have PDB's (Actually I am unable to find same in output directory.
- If no then how to debug activeX code from VC++ code. Note I am having source code and DLL. I cannot compile source code because i dont have VB 6.0 environment.

Comment: You would use the VB6 development environment (IDE) to debug the ActiveX control written in VB6.  You'll need to obtain VB6 in order to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code compiled with VB6 doesn't provide a "PDB" file, as it's really not intended to be debugged outside of the VB6 IDE. While you might be able to do some amount of direct debugging without any symbols or other assistance, just like you might with any program where symbols aren't available, it sure isn't going to be easy.

The standard approach would be to use the real VB6 IDE to load the project file, and use its debugger. You would generally be debugging the component separately from the host that's embedding the component, though it is possible to [debug the component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa733600%28v%3Dvs.60%29) within the IDE while it's in use by the host container.

Comment: And ... if you are trying to use something like Windbg, and the project properties was to compile to P-code (instead of Native Code), then what you're debugging is the vb runtime p-code interpreter, not the actual app code!

Comment: FWIW *Project -> Props -> Compile -> Create symbolic debug info* will generate a PDB for the project.

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks for the tip. It's been ages since I actually opened up a VB6 IDE. Feel free to write your own answer with that information; it seems useful.